# MapKit вращение userLocationView.arrow по ходу движения

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, position, yandexmapkit, mapkit

Использую android map kit, на карте включен userLocationLayer, при движении появляется стандартная (желтая) стрелка отражающая местоположение и направление движения. 
Есть возможность заменить стрелку своей иконкой: arrow.setIcon(arrowPlaceMarkImage), но в таком случае при движении своя иконка не вращается.

```
    userLocationLayer.isEnabled = true
    userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true

    userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(object : UserLocationObjectListener {
        override fun onObjectUpdated(p0: UserLocationView, p1: ObjectEvent) {
        }

        override fun onObjectRemoved(p0: UserLocationView) {}

        override fun onObjectAdded(userLocationView: UserLocationView) {
            userLocationView.arrow.setIcon(arrowPlaceMarkImage)
            userLocationView.pin.setIcon(userPlaceMarkImage)
            userLocationView.accuracyCircle.fillColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }
    })
```

Есть возможность заставить свою иконку вращаться по ходу движения?

Answer (score 2):

В общем разобрался: нужно задать RotationType, когда устанавливаешь кастомную иконку. Вот пример со сложной иконкой:

```
val pinIcon = userLocationView.arrow.useCompositeIcon()

            pinIcon.setIcon(
                    "icon",
                    arrowPlaceMarkImage,
                    IconStyle().setAnchor(PointF(0.5f, 1f))
                            .setRotationType(RotationType.ROTATE)
                            .setZIndex(0f)
            )

            pinIcon.setIcon(
                    "pin",
                    userPlaceMarkImage,
                    IconStyle().setAnchor(PointF(0.5f, 0.5f))
                            .setRotationType(RotationType.NO_ROTATION)
                            .setZIndex(1f)
            )
```